# Making my listview scroll instead of disappearing behind my footer

Tags: jquery, list, mobile

This  is what I currently have going on: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjiAt.png

Basically, it's a list that uses jQuery and some AJAX to hit a webservice which hits a database and pulls the respective dogs based on the users selections in the previous menu.

This is for a mobile app, and I'd like the ability to scroll the list up/down while keeping the header/footer stuck in their respective positions.

Here is the relevant code:

list :

`<div ID="dogs" style="text-align:center;width:100%;overflow:auto ">`

footer :

`<div data-role="footer" id="footer" class="footer" style="background:     url('images/footer.png');width:100%;height:87px;">
footer {position: absolute; bottom: 0; z-index: 1;}`

Now, in doing research I found that before using the touchOverflow, I have to add this:

`<script> $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){ $.mobile.touchOverflowEnabled = true; }); </script>`

Which I have, and have had no luck. So it seems to me that I either need to do some CSS magic, or jQuery has something else up its' sleeve for me. Either way, I'd love your help !

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `position: fixed` on your footer.

Comment: That is almost good enough. However, I need the footer to remain at the bottom of the screen where a footer should be on a mobile app. 

With that addition to the code, the footer jumps up and depending on what's on the screen it moves around. 

Anything else?